# Deploy AMP Server-side rendering with CloudFlare Workers

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, amp-html

We want to deploy a function based on AMP Optimizer https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ampproject/toolbox-optimizer with the functions of CloudFlare Workers https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/quickstart/

But when installing via npm:
`npm install @ampproject/toolbox-optimizer`

When trying to deploy the function, it always throws different errors

```
⬇️ Installing wranglerjs...
⬇️ Installing wasm-pack...
  ./index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cheerio' in '/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr'
resolve 'cheerio' in '/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules
        using description file: /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/cheerio)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/cheerio doesn't exist
            .wasm
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/cheerio.wasm doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/cheerio.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/cheerio.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/cheerio.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/cheerio doesn't exist
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/node_modules]
[/Users/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/cheerio]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/cheerio.wasm]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/cheerio.mjs]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/cheerio.js]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/cheerio.json]
 @ ./index.js 23:16-34
./index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'export.js' in '/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr'
resolve 'export.js' in '/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules
        using description file: /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/export.js)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/export.js doesn't exist
            .wasm
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/export.js.wasm doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/export.js.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/export.js.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/export.js.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/export.js doesn't exist
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/node_modules]
[/Users/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/export.js]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/export.js.wasm]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/export.js.mjs]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/export.js.js]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/export.js.json]
 @ ./index.js 22:21-41
./index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr'
resolve 'fs' in '/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules
        using description file: /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/package.json (relative path: .)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs is not a file
            .wasm
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs.wasm doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              existing directory
                use ./index.js from main in package.json
                  using description file: /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/package.json (relative path: .)
                    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                    using description file: /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/package.json (relative path: ./index.js)
                      no extension
                        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                        /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index.js doesn't exist
                      .wasm
                        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                        /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index.js.wasm doesn't exist
                      .mjs
                        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                        /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index.js.mjs doesn't exist
                      .js
                        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                        /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index.js.js doesn't exist
                      .json
                        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                        /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index.js.json doesn't exist
                      as directory
                        /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index.js doesn't exist
                using path: /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index
                  using description file: /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/package.json (relative path: ./index)
                    no extension
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index doesn't exist
                    .wasm
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index.wasm doesn't exist
                    .mjs
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index.mjs doesn't exist
                    .js
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index.js doesn't exist
                    .json
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      /Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index.json doesn't exist
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/node_modules]
[/Users/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs.wasm]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs.mjs]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs.js]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs.json]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index.js]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index.js.wasm]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index.js.mjs]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index.js.js]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index.js.json]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index.wasm]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index.mjs]
[/Users/martinjuzefiszyn/ssr/node_modules/fs/index.json]
 @ ./index.js 20:11-24
Error: webpack returned an error. You may be able to resolve this issue by running npm install.
```

Any ideas because there are dependencies that throw us error when trying to preview the CloudFlare function?

Any other idea to implement the function in any layer of the user to be able to server optimized amp pages? Install NodeJs in Apache? AWS Lambda?

Comment: This is difficult to analyze because there might be many reason why you see the errors. Can you prune your build so that you see only one error; e.g. just the issues related to `cheerio`?

Comment: It's a bit weird that cheerio is listed as a dependency (which doesn't come from toolbox-optimizer. Here is a working cloudworker demo which might be helpful: https://github.com/cramforce/amp-toolbox-optimizer-worker

Comment: @SebastianBenz We put together a function based on the example of github.com/cramforce/amp-toolbox-optimizer-worker but we had to apply several changes that throw error in the worker, I analyze some additional points and I comment. Thank you